# Error 65 with react-native cli, Xcode throws an error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

[image: Xcode]

App works great on Android build failed with **error code 65** on IOS **in DEBUG mode**

- What I've did :

```
pod update
pod install
```

**Package.json** :

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

**In Release Mode**:

The app doesn't have any image, but successfuly launches.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build and pod install , then run the app again?

Comment: Yes already did :/